# F# Seq.next - what's the correct pattern?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture, f#, seq

As part of a project that uses the Strategy Pattern, I'm trying to write a function, that creates a function, which returns the next value of an infinite sequence each  time it is applied. At the moment I am doing it using this dodgy **GetNext** function:

```
let GetNext<'T> (enumerator:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<'T>) =
    let n = enumerator.MoveNext()
    enumerator.Current

let FunctionFactory<'T> =
    let s = 0.0 |> Seq.unfold (fun i -> Some(i, if 0.0 = i then 1.0 else 0.0))
    let enumerator = s.GetEnumerator()
    (fun (ignoredParam:'T) -> GetNext enumerator )
```

I would like **FunctionFactory** to look like this:

```
let FunctionFactory<'T> =
    let s = 0.0 |> Seq.unfold (fun i -> Some(i, if 0.0 = i then 1.0 else 0.0))
    (fun (ignoredParam:'T) -> Seq.next s )
```

The *ignoredParam* is used in other functions that pass through the same strategy pattern and depend on the context it provides. Since this looks so bad, really I have two questions. Why isn't there a **Seq.next**? What is the correct/elegant way of implementing *a wide variety of sequence expressions that can be injected into a strategy framework like* this?

*Edited following Fyodor Soikin's answer* - Sequence expressions appeal to me at the moment because they help me to think about the problems I'm looking at. Rather than mutable imperative style code, I'd like to build on this pattern with more complex input sequences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you noticed that you never dispose of the enumerator?
This is why there is no `Seq.next`: its usage would require unsound design.

As for the second question, it is not entirely clear what is "this" that you're trying to implement. As far as I can glean from the code, you're trying to produce a "stateful procedure" that will yield 1.0 or 0.0, switching every time it is called. Right?

If so, I would do it via a mutable value. A lot less overhead than a sequence:

```
let FunctionFactory<'T> =
    let mutable flag = true
    fun (_:'T) -> 
       flag <- not flag
       if flag then 1.0 else 0.0
```

Comment: Why do I need to dispose the enumerator? Isn't it garbage collected when I drop all the references to the returned function? I appreciate this alternative way of implementing the factory function. I was designing my application with the intention of defining a large variety of sequence expressions beyond this simple example, I'll update the question to reflect that, will it change your answer to the second part?

Comment: In this particular case, the enumerator will be picked up by GC, of course. But if you want to work with sequences in general, you must correctly implement the contract, and that contract clearly says that enumerators must be deterministically destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, I don't like it but it makes sense when I browse the library implementation, I see now how many of the Seq.* function are like a scoped enumeration: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs

Comment: Look at it the other way around: what you're looking for is simple _not a sequence_. Because you want it to adhere to a contract that is not that of F# sequence. So just make your own contract! :-)